# C Recursion PATH

Tags: c, clang

i have an exercice where i find the solution to reverse string, but i'm a little bit confuse about the path =>

```
char        *reverse_string(char *str1)
    {
                static int i=0;
                static char revstr[sizeof(str1) / sizeof(str1[0])];
                if(*str1)
                {
                     reverse_string(str1+1);
                     revstr[i++] = *str1;
                }
                return revstr;           
    }
    
int         main(void) 
{
            char arr[] = "abcdefghjk";
            
            print_string(reverse_string(arr));
            return (0);
}
```

Ok this code work fine, but i don't understand why the second one doesn't work, can someone explain me the path/way on theses ?

```
char        *reverse_string(char *str1)
{
            static int i=0;
            static char revstr[sizeof(str1) / sizeof(str1[0])];
            if(*str1)
            {
                 reverse_string(str1+1);
            }
                 revstr[i++] = *str1;
            
            return revstr;           
}

int         main(void) 
{
            char arr[] = "abcdefghjk";
            
            print_string(reverse_string(arr));
            return (0);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(str1)` is the size of the pointer, not the size/length of the string. You create UB when the size of the pointer is smaller than the string (which is likely). use `strlen(str1)+1` for the length of the string + `\0`-Byte (but that will not work for static arrays)

Comment: In the second example, you set element 0 of the array where `str1` points to initially (array `arr`) to `'\0'`, which means the string ends there.

Comment: I don't understand because it's doesnt work too when i put manually the size of array

Comment: I mean, normally when the stack decompiles it is supposed to work with the old values that's why I put a =>

revstr [i ++] = * str1;

in order to retrieve the elements one by one, suddenly what I don't understand is that in the second example it doesn't do this job, no matter the size of the array

Comment: The size problem does not have any visual effect at the moment. UB means UB and this includes behaving as expected. The array size problem is present in both cases and isn't the cause of the the string ending early.

Comment: @pharoah111 Did you delete question"?

Comment: Does it have to be recursive / do you use it to learn about recursion or is it no problem using it without recursion? It would be simpler without.

Comment: I think you snuck your answer in first, and we're both getting at the same thing, but the array size is fine.  The issue, and we both pointed it out is that the first character ends up being 0.

Comment: No i dont delete the question.

Comment: and @12431234123412341234123 , no its for me, to better understand details , i really want to learn C

Comment: Recursion is difficult to understand, easy to overlook, and yet it's one of the most powerful aspects of computing.

Comment: the difference with recursion is that for once the computer works in its own way, it totally changes from imperative programming, but hey, anyway, it is important to master it

Comment: @user56983 No, the array size is not fine. The array size is too small when `sizeof char * < 11`, which is likely.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

```
        if(*str1)
        {
             reverse_string(str1+1);
        }
             revstr[i++] = *str1;
```

This code means call `reverse_string()` if we are not at the string ending `'\0'`-Byte yet and set the element where `revstr[i]` points to to the current element (regardless if we are at the `'\0'`-Byte or not). If `str1` points to the string ending `'\0'`-Byte, it sets the byte 0 (because `i` is 0) of `revstr` to 0 / `'\0'`, so that the string now ends there.

But there is a much bigger problem in your code, already mentioned: Your revstr array hasn't the correct length. I think a better approach would be to give the array to change at function call. Or, as an alternative, you could alloc the needed buffer with `malloc()`.

How i would solve that problem, without recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//restrict because this arrays should not overlap
char *reverse_string(const char * restrict orginal, char * restrict rev)
{
  size_t i=0;
  size_t j=strlen(orginal)-1; //j is indexing the last char
  while(orginal[i])
    {
      //go from end to the beginnign with j. Inside the the string, excluding '\0'
      //go from start to the end with i. Inside the the string, excluding '\0'
      rev[j--] = orginal[i++];
    }
  rev[i]='\0'; //end the string at the i.th position.

  return rev;
}

int main(void) 
{
  char arr[] = "abcdefghjk";
  char rev[ sizeof arr ];
  
  // i used puts() because i don't have your print_string() function
  puts(reverse_string(arr,rev));
  return 0; //return is not a function, no need for the () here
}
```

Or with recursion, without needing `strlen()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_stringSub(const char * restrict orginal, char * restrict rev, size_t *pos)
{
  if(*orginal)
  {
    reverse_stringSub(orginal+1,rev,pos);
    rev[(*pos)++] = *orginal;
  }
}

char *reverse_string(const char * restrict orginal, char * restrict rev)
{
  size_t pos=0;
  reverse_stringSub(orginal,rev,&pos);
  rev[pos]='\0';

  return rev;
}

int main(void) 
{
  char arr[] = "abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxuzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXUZ";
  char rev[ sizeof arr ];
  
  puts(reverse_string(arr,rev));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohhh okay, i feel very dumb, i think it was another thing. Thanks you a lot and thx for this example too.

Comment: i understand with printing this: printf("%i -- %c \n ", i, *str1); It clearly shows me that it directly closes this character chain before having seen the light of day

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings defined by the type `char*` are null terminated, meaning that if `char* ptrA;` is a variable `ptrA` represents a memory location. Then `ptrA[n]` for some numeric value `n` is going to be of type `char`.

If you look, the term for the unary operator `*(ptrA)` is called the dereferencing operator.  And when you dereference a memory location with a program, you're accessing the value of the data at that memory location.

The second code sample doesn't work, because `if(*str1)` asks if the first memory location in the string is the null terminator or `0`, and then you have a recursive function call `reverse_string(str1+1)`, which does the same thing, but for the next memory location.  So you have these function calls loaded on to the stack---just like a stack of paper or a stack of playing cards.  You'll see the expression 'pushed onto the stack'.  And then that next expression `revstr[i++] = *str1;`  isn't called until each call to `reverse_string` is terminated and that happens when each function call is popped off the "top" of the stack in reverse order.

If you pick apart the expression `revstr[i++] = *str1;` The `i++` part happens after `revstr[i] = *str1`; the variable `i` being static means that it is initialized to `0` only the first time `reverse_string` is called, so the value is conserved, and the same for `revstr`.

In the second code sample, when `*str1` is zero, `reverse_string` is not called again, but the memory location for the null terminator is loaded into the first character of `revstr`, because the assignment happens as the recursive calls return from execution.  It works properly in the first code sample, because in the first one, if you have NULL it never made the assignment into `revstr[]`

Comment: Thank's for taking your time to explain, just i try to understand why with this :

if(*str1)
            {
                 reverse_string(str1+1, n);
            }
            
            printf("%i \n", *str1);
            revstr[i++] = *str1;

i can read perfectly the values i need for the array

Comment: Yeah it reads fine and the bounds of the array aren't overflowed.  But---because those variables --- `i` and `revstr[]` are both static --- the function only works the first time you call it.

Comment: It happens to work on AMD64, but it is still UB. Change the array length and it works everywhere without UB.